# Getting date from DatePicker without using Dialog

Tags: android, date, android-activity, datepicker

i have the DatePicker on my mainActivity.xml that the user will be able to simply use the + and - to change date. How can i get the date from this without using a dialog. Meaning the user will just adjust the date using the + and - for day month year and then when the user clicks the ADD button, it will pull the date that the user set.

Comment: Have you tried to implement onDateChangedListener in your activity?